# How do try_cast error handling in a query with long results

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, try-cast

I'm trying to figure out how to catch errors and also find out when one of the try_cast's returns null.  My query within my stored procedure looks like this:

```
   SELECT
          try_cast(ORI.body AS xml).value('(/BODY/@formid)[1]', 'INT') AS 'Form ID'
        , try_cast(ORI.body AS xml).value('(/BODY/@form_answers)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'Body'
        , ORN.info_id
        , getdate() as create_date
    FROM
        ORG_NOTEPAD ORN
    INNER JOIN
        ORG_INFO ORI ON ORN.info_id = ORI.id
    WHERE 
        COALESCE(ORI.template_id,0)<>0 
    AND 
        COALESCE(ORN.case_id,0)<> 0 
    AND 
        ORN.type_id <> 4
```

This query returns about 800 lines.  There are 3 separate try-casts in this.

I know that each of the try_cast's can return null, but any of them can also return an error message.  How do I run this query, but also find any try_cast result that returns a null or error message?  I need to get details of what had null or error message in the result, like info_id and form id, and write the error info and context to an error table. But I'm also going to write the "good" results to a separate table.

I find lots of [examples of things that will cause an error](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/60629/use-try_cast-function-sql-server/), but in this, I need to capture more individual info about null or error messages. The closest thing I found was [this stored procedure example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615748/stored-procedure-try-cast), but I'm having trouble applying the info to my example.

I'm not sure if I need to utilize case statements and a temp table with the individual try_cast's, or about the error handling/null/good answer handling.

I'm rather new to stored procedures and also try_cast, etc.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI, don't use `COALESCE` on your columns in the `WHERE`, it makes the query non-SARGable. Use proper Boolean logic and handle the `NULL` value(s).

Comment: On your question, I'm not sure I follow. `TRY_CAST` won't error; that's the point. It will return `NULL` if the value can't be converted. It will also return `NULL` if the value was already `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #ORG_INFO
(
id int identity(1,1),
body nvarchar(max)
);

insert into #ORG_INFO(body)
values
(N'<BODY formid="1234"/>'),
(NULL), --just null
(N'<BODY>'), --invalid xml
(N'<BODY formid="abcd"/>'), --formid not a number
(N'<BODY anotherattrib="1234"/>'); --missing @formid

select 
case 
    when body is null then cast('body is null' as varchar(100))
    when try_cast(body as xml) is null then 'invalid xml'
    when try_cast(body as xml).exist('/BODY/@formid') = 0 then 'missing formid'
    when try_cast(body as xml).exist('xs:integer((/BODY/@formid)[1])') = 0 then 'non-numeric formid'
    else 'ok'   
end as ctrlmsg,
try_cast(body as xml).value('xs:integer((/BODY/@formid)[1])', 'int') as formid,
*
from #ORG_INFO;


drop table #ORG_INFO;
```